# Splunk Custom Index Searching

Tags: splunk

I created my own index in Splunk to be used by the HTTP Event Collector. When I look at the Indexes view, I see that there are events in my index.

However, when I go into the Search App, and look at the Data Summary, on the Sources tab, I am not seeing any entry for my index.

I was using a different token for HEC previous to this, pointing to the 'main' index, and that data is there, as source type 'json_no_timestamp'. But when I pointed to my own index, I can't get it to show in Search.

One interesting thing I noticed is that in the Index view, all the other entries show 'system' in the 'App' column, whereas my index has 'search' there instead.

Do I need to do something to get my index to show up?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the 'index="myIndex"' parameter in the search. Unfortunately, it looks like my index just won't show up in the Data Summary, though - it looks like that always defaults to 'main'.